# ¿Cómo se puede acceder a las líneas de un marco de datos de múltiples índices?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Quiero acceder a las líneas que tienen tanto el ID de la tienda X como el ID del artículo Y. Puedo filtrar para uno pero no para ambos.

```
                                     date            item_price item_cnt_day
                                      min        max       mean          sum
date_block_num shop_id item_id                                              
1              5       30      2013-02-16 2013-02-25      399.0          5.0
                       31      2013-02-16 2013-02-24      699.0          3.0
                       32      2013-02-15 2013-02-15      349.0          2.0
                       33      2013-02-10 2013-02-24      499.0          3.0
                       35      2013-02-15 2013-02-15      399.0          1.0
...                                   ...        ...        ...          ...
33             5       22100   2015-10-06 2015-10-06      629.0          1.0
                       22102   2015-10-10 2015-10-21     1250.0          5.0
                       22104   2015-10-27 2015-10-27      249.0          1.0
                       22163   2015-10-24 2015-10-24      169.0          1.0
                       22164   2015-10-15 2015-10-15      549.0          1.0
```

En efecto intenté con:

```
print(sales_monthly.loc[sales_monthly.index.get_level_values(1) == row['shop_id']])
```

## Actualizacion

Intenté con:

```
sales_monthly.loc[sales_monthly.index.get_level_values(1) == row['shop_id'] & sales_monthly.index.get_level_values(2) == row['item_id']]
```

Pero me devuelve:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'numpy.int64' and 'Int64Index'
```

En efecto, `sales_monthly.index.get_level_values(2) == row['item_id']` me devuelve:

```
[False False False ... False False False]
```

Comment: Intenta con `print(sales_monthly.loc[sales_monthly.index.get_level_values(1) == row['shop_id'] & sales_monthly.index.get_level_values(2) == row['item_id']])` un solo apmersand

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# MultiIndex con método xs()
# seleccionar datos usando como argumento los niveles de un dataframe pandas

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

matriz = [np.array([ 'cor', 'cor', 'lug', 'lug', 'our', 'our', 'pon', 'pon']),\
np.array( [ 'uno', 'dos', 'uno', 'dos', 'uno', 'dos', 'uno', 'dos' ] ) ]
            
df = pd.DataFrame ( np.random.rand(8,4), index = matriz,\
columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

print()
print ( ' imprimo dataframe df ')
print ( df )

print()
print ( ' imprimo niveles ')
print (df.index.get_level_values(0))
print (df.index.get_level_values(1))

print()
print ( ' imprimo segundo nivel ')
print (df.xs('uno', level=1))

print()
print ( ' imprimo dos niveles ')
print (df.xs( ('uno', 'cor'), level = (1,0) ) )
```

El método a usar es xs() que toma como argumentos los niveles (puede usarse con su valor entero o su nombre como string)